# Microsoft Azure Backup Agent -- (0x186D9)

Tags: azure, microsoft

After downloading Azure Backup Agent only one of our laptops has been able to successfully complete a full C:\ Drive backup. On the rest I keep getting the same error "C:\ The current backup operation failed because the number of data transfer failures was more than 1000 Specified files could not be processed. Please check if the volume where scratch space is configured is not full and retry the operation after addressing the individual errors in the log. (0x186D9)". Does anyone know where could be the issue here?

Comment: The volume where scratch space is configured is fine fyi

Comment: I was able to complete a backup in one of the folders in C:\. The available space in the laptop that actually completed the entire drive is less than the rest of them. I haven't been able to find a solution on the web. Thanks.